Shouldn't this be considered a double pointer?
I'm a novice C programmer, and I have what is probably a simple question.  I'm learning about using pointers to structs currently, and I can't understand why lines 20 or 22 below work.  I understand that scanf() requires you to provide the address of the variable to which you want to assign a value. But since this scanf() placed in the scope of a function which takes a pointer to a struct as an argument, why isn't "&k->avg" considered a double pointer?  If you cascade the values through, isn't the aforementioned equal to "&&s->avg"?
// Online C compiler to run C program online
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>


#include <stdio.h>
struct student {
       float avg;
       int roll;
};
void read(struct student *);
void display(struct student *);
void main() {
     struct student s;
     read(&s);
     display(&s);
}
void read(struct student *k) {
     printf("Enter the average of the student : ");
     scanf("%f", &k->avg);
     printf("Enter the roll number of the student : ");
     scanf("%d", &k->roll);
}
void display(struct student *k) {
     printf("Given details are :\nRoll Number of the student : %d\nAverage mark of the student                                                                : %f\n", k->roll, k->avg);
}

I tried taking away the "&" but I get a segmentation error when I do that.  Leaving the "&" in place, the code works fine.

What if I tell you that -> is the "un-pointer" operator (dereference would be the proper term), does that make something click?

@Gimby I like to call it the object-of operator. :)

avg is a float, not a double.  Perhaps by "double pointer" you mean "pointer to pointer".  That is a horrible abuse of language that is far too common.

In the function read, the parameter k is a pointer to your structure.
When using k->avg you therefore get your float.
However, the function scanf expects a pointer to a float.
&k->avg does this work for you.
Writing &(k->avg) would make the whole thing more readable.
UPDATE:
You should consider the operator precedence in C:
-> has the precedence over &.
So &k->avg results in &(k->avg) and not (&k)->avg.

x->y is nothing more than shorthand for (*x).y.  This is known as "syntactic sugar" in programming language design.  So &k->avg is equivalent to &(*k).avg.
Now just break it down:  *k has type struct student.  So (*k).avg has type float.  So &(*k).avg has type float *.  If you take away the &, then you'd be passing a float to scanf, which is never correct.  scanf requires a pointer to the target variable so that it can store the value into it.

Your expression k->avg is identical to ((*k).avg). It means that the type of your expression is a float. The indirection of the k pointer has been resolved and the expression represents the float. scanf now needs the address in memory of the floating point so that it can fill the variable with the value. That's the role of the &. &((*k).avg)
This said, it is possible to take the address of a pointer giving what you named a double pointer &k but that something else.


why isn't "&k->avg" considered a double pointer?

Because the expression k->avg is not a pointer; it's a float.
Somewhere in memory you have a struct student
   +------+
s: | avg  |
   +------+
   | roll |
   +------+
     

Somewhere else in memory you have a pointer k which stores the address of s:
   +---+         +------+
k: |   | ---> s: | avg  |
   +---+         +------+
                 | roll |
                 +------+

The expression *k is a kinda-sorta alias for s; reading and writing *k is the same as reading and writing s.
The expression k->avg is shorthand for (*k).avg; the -> implicitly dereferences k, so k->avg isn't pointing to s.avg, it is s.avg.
       k == &s     // struct student * == struct student *
      *k ==  s     // struct student   == struct student
(*k).avg ==  s.avg // float            == float

